# Oracle. Create index on a DATE column

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I would like to know if creating an index in the field `CREATION_DATE` will make any improvement in this query

```
   select TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR, count ('1')  MESSAGE_HOUR
        from t_hotel             
           where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
group by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') 
    order by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') ;
```

Comment: Is `CREATION_DATE` a text column?  If so, then change your table design and make it a date column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take advantage of a function-based index on `CREATION_DATE` column.

Take the following demo as an example where I have a table with a column of `date` type.

> ```
> create table t_hotel  (creation_date date);
> ```

> ```
> insert into t_hotel select sysdate+0.5 from dual connect by level <=100;
> ```
>
> ```
> 100 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into t_hotel select sysdate+0.2 from dual connect by level <=100;
> ```
>
> ```
> 100 rows affected
> ```

> ```
>  explain plan for  select TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR, count ('1')  MESSAGE_HOUR
>         from t_hotel             
>            where trunc(creation_date)= trunc(sysdate) 
> group by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') 
>     order by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                              |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 353888308                                                     |
> |                                                                                |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |         |   200 |  1800 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |         |   200 |  1800 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_HOTEL |   200 |  1800 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> |                                                                                |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                            |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                            |
> |                                                                                |
> |    2 - filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("CREATION_DATE"))=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)       |
> |               )                                                                |
> |                                                                                |
> | Note                                                                           |
> | -----                                                                          |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                        |
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_cd on t_hotel(trunc(creation_date));
> ```

> ```
>  explain plan for  select TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR, count ('1')  MESSAGE_HOUR
>         from t_hotel             
>            where trunc(creation_date)= trunc(sysdate) 
> group by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') 
>     order by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                        |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 2841908389                                                              |
> |                                                                                          |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |     2 |    36 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  SORT GROUP BY               |         |     2 |    36 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_HOTEL |     2 |    36 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_CD  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                          |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                      |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                      |
> |                                                                                          |
> |    3 - access(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("CREATION_DATE"))=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))                |
> |                                                                                          |
> | Note                                                                                     |
> | -----                                                                                    |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                  |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9215e4a3b25a70f19a75700da68b32e9)*

Comment: `(creation_date date);` The very first comment by `Tim` is that the column itself is not a `DATE` column. Even from OP question, the datatype of the column is not clear but looking at the query it looks like a `varchar`

Comment: If that column is `varchar2` then I think OP can't use `TO_CHAR` function with data formatting string.

Comment: You must put as an `Assumption` in your answer.

Comment: @XING, there is absolutely no reason, on the basis of the question as asked, to assume the column is anything but a date. After all, they explicitly say *it is a date column* in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

1) where clause should be written differently. 
 `where creation_date >= trunc(sysdate) and creation_date < trunc(sysdate+1)`
2) You can create two index.
   - normal `create index idx_creation_date on t_hotel(creation_date);`  improve where clause.
   - fucntion base index `create index idx_creation_date_hh24 on t_hotel(TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') );`  probably it will improve group by and orderby but i'm not sure.